# reduce executable size mixing dynamically / static compilations

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-optimization

I am coding a project using c++ under visual c++ 2017 , but I would like to know if I could compile dynamically my project , and add `#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32")` only once for all the project my project looks like

```c
./project.cpp
    utils.cpp   
    utils.h
    server.cpp  
    server.h
    api.cpp
    api.h
    60+ files
```

main.cpp

```
#include "utils.h"
#include "server.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32")
Server server;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    server.monitoring();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to compile all project dinamically , and only add `#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32")` and be useful for all the project . I am compiling the project like this `cl project.cpp utils.cpp server.cpp api.cpp /DYNAMICBASE:NO /MD /Ot` this give me 14k , and it's okay ,but if I change for `/MT` because I need the program is executed under every windows machine. I got 223k , but I would like to know if I could cut down a little bit more the memory if it's possible ~50k

Comment: Are you having some kind of problem with `/MD`?  That is the setting for dynamic linkage to the standard library.

Comment: the problem is that I want to setup dynamically , but also add ws2_32 without increasing too much like 200k

Comment: You should be able to add a link to ws2_32 and use the `/MD` option.  ws2_32.dll should be installed on every Windows machine, so you should not need to locate it manually.

Comment: if I compile and send my project.exe to windows machine it doesnt work it says I need the dll

Comment: What version of Windows are you deploying to?

Comment: I am using windows 10 , and msvs 2019